# Как распознать ipad на jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ipad

Как распознать ipad на jquery? На сайте есть флэшка, флэш на айпадах не отображается, сделал альтернативное решения, хочу написать условия: если устройство айпад, то флэшка скрывается а картинка показывается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Определяйте не iPad, а наличие Flash.

Самое, наверное, удобное — используя [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), там есть [статья](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html) по этому вопросу. В качестве fallback'а только выдавать не как в статье «установите flash», а альтернативное решение (картинку или что у Вас там).